# What are NoSql Key/Value databases used for

Tags: nosql, key-value-store

I have been hearing alot about nosql key/value databases online now. Can you give an example of what one is used for. What kind of real world data is best for these kind of databases?

Comment: I don't understand the downvote? This is a valid question, isn't it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think '[What the heck are you actually using NoSQL for](http://highscalability.com/blog/2010/12/6/what-the-heck-are-you-actually-using-nosql-for.html)' is an excellent read for real life usage cases for NoSQL databases. Let me quote some of them here:

- Managing large streams of non-transactional data: Apache logs, application logs, MySQL logs, clickstreams, etc.
- Syncing online and offline data. This is a niche CouchDB has targeted. 
  Fast response times under all loads.
- Avoiding heavy joins for when the query load for complex joins become too large for a RDBMS.
- Soft real-time systems where low latency is critical. Games are one example.
- Applications where a wide variety of different write, read, query, and consistency patterns need to be supported. There are systems optimized for 50% reads 50% writes, 95% writes, or 95% reads.
- Read-only applications needing extreme speed and resiliency, simple
  queries, and can tolerate slightly stale data.
- Applications requiring moderate performance, read/write access, simple queries, completely
  authoritative data.
- Read-only application which complex query requirements.
- Load balance to accommodate data and usage concentrations and to help keep microprocessors busy.
- Real-time inserts, updates, and queries.
- Hierarchical data like threaded discussions and parts explosion.
- Dynamic table creation.
- Two tier applications where low latency data is made available through a fast NoSQL interface, but the data itself can be calculated and updated by high latency Hadoop apps or other low priority apps.
- Sequential data reading. The right underlying data storage model needs to be selected. A B-tree may not be the best model for sequential reads.
- Slicing off part of service that may need better performance/scalability onto it's own system. For example, user logins may need to be high performance and this feature could use a dedicated service to meet those goals.
- Caching. A  high performance caching tier for web sites and other applications. Example is a cache for the Data Aggregation System used by the Large Hadron Collider.
- Voting.
- Real-time page view counters.
- User registration, profile, and session data.
- Document, catalog management  and content management systems. These are facilitated by the ability to store complex documents has a whole rather than organized as relational tables. Similar logic applies to inventory, shopping carts, and other structured data types.
- Archiving. Storing a large continual stream of data that is still accessible on-line.
- Document-oriented databases with a flexible schema that can handle schema changes over time.
- Analytics. Use MapReduce, Hive, or Pig to perform analytical queries and scale-out systems that support high write loads.

Comment: Thanks..I thought id be able to use it on my next project but I guess not. I think a graph database may be more appropriate. again thanks for your explaination.